# Change pixel color in Rmagick

Tags: ruby, rmagick

I know how to get the color of a pixel with Rmagick:

`image.pixel_color(0,0)`.

But, how do you change the value of that pixel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pixel_color takes a third arguments which is the color to use for the current pixel. This can be either a color name like 'white' or an instance of Pixel.

Example: `img = image.pixel_color(0,0, 'white')`